# ReactJS error: it saying "Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" 17 stack frames were collapsed. Module.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './Header'
import Home from './Home'
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <Header />
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/checkout">
            <Header />
            <h1>Hello I am a checkout page</h1>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is my app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Product.css';
const Product = ({ id, title, image, price, rating }) => {
    return (
        <div className="product">
            <div className="product__info">
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p className="product__price">
                    <small>$</small>
                    <strong>{price}</strong>
                </p>
                <div className="product__rating">
                    {Array(rating)
                        .fill()
                        .map((_, i) => (
                            <p></p>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src={image} alt="" />
            <button>Add to Basket</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

This is Product.js where I take props id,title,image,price,rating
and make the product card

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ShoppingBasketIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingBasket";

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <img className="header__logo" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG11.png" />
            <div className="header__search">
                <input className="header_searchInput" type="text" />
                <SearchIcon className="header_searchIcon" />
            </div>
            <div className="header__nav">
                <div className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOn">
                        Hello Guest
                    </span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTw">
                        Sign In
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOn">
                        Returns
                    </span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTw">
                        & Orders
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOn">
                        Your
                    </span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTw">
                        Prime
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="header_optionBasket">
                    <ShoppingBasketIcon />
                    <span className="header_optionalLineTwo header__basketCount">0</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

and this is my Header.js where I built the header

```
import React from 'react'
import './home.css'
import Product from './Product'
import { product1, product2, product3 } from './data'

function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="home">
            <div className="home__container">
                <img className="home__image" src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/digital/video/merch2016/Hero/Covid19/Generic/GWBleedingHero_ENG_COVIDUPDATE__XSite_1500x600_PV_en-GB._CB428684220_.jpg" alt="" />

                <div className="home__row">
                    {
                        product1.map((item) => (
                            <Product
                                id={item.id}
                                title={item.title}
                                price={item.price}
                                rating={item.rating}
                                image={item.image}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="home__row">
                    {
                        product2.map((item) => (
                            <Product
                                id={item.id}
                                title={item.title}
                                price={item.price}
                                rating={item.rating}
                                image={item.image}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="home__row">
                    {
                        product3.map((item) => (
                            <Product
                                id={item.id}
                                title={item.title}
                                price={item.price}
                                rating={item.rating}
                                image={item.image}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

and finally this is my Home.js where I basically built the home page

```
{
  "name": "amazon-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my package.json file

I want to change my route to the checkout page but I am getting location is not defined

can some please explain to me what's the error I am getting and how do I resolve it!!!

and also please explain why am I getting the error

Comment: Where do you try to access `location`? Please provide a reproducible code

Comment: what do you mean by access the location?

Comment: Are u aware that you will never be able to access the `checkout` page? Since you are using a `switch` and since you have put the "/" route at the top, it is always going to render the "/" route

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Put the `checkout` path at the top. Just switch both `route` declarations

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma are you not calling `something.location` somewhere?

Comment: the route order was the first thing. As @SinanYaman mentioned, you are calling .location somewhere

Comment: okay i'll check it

Comment: @FireFighter hey check i have added some more component maybe you find something there!

Comment: got the mistake thank you so much guys

Comment: I assume `import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, ... }` is a typo...